# Common elements among multiple lists

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, search, collections

I need to find all common elements (if duplicates exist in all lists, they must be listed as many times) among multiple pre-sorted lists. The number of lists will be determined by the user. I'm trying to find an algorithm that has an O(n) effiency.

I have been toying with the below code, but I can't figure out how to make this work if I don't already know how many lists there are:

```
Integer[] a = {2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11};
Integer[] b = {2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 14}
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
while(i < a.length && j < b.length) {
   if(a[i] == b[j]) {
      System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
      i++;
      j++;
   } else if(a[i] > b[j]) {
        j++;
   } else {
        i++;
   }
}
```

desired output: 2 2 7

Comment: Use `Set`s instead of this approach, it has O(N) efficiency.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That doesn't cover the case of duplicates. Unless you have some library's `Multiset` anyway.

Comment: @immibis well, use `Map<Integer, Integer>` where the key is the element and the value is counter of how many elements are for this key. A `Set` is just a `Map<WhateverKeyYouWantOrNeed, Boolean>`

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza does using Set deal with the unknown quantity of lists until runtime?

Comment: what do you mean by the unknown quantity of lists until runtime?

Comment: I won't be defining the lists in this method. The lists will be passed to this method by the user. So there can be any quantity of lists in the collection.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza There's no need to throw the numbers into a different data structure. They're already sorted.

Comment: @JohnKugelman oh, I didn't read that part. Then, it's a piece of cake, you just have to traverse both arrays at the *same* time.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza But I don't know how many arrays the user will pass into this method. Forget about the a= and b= in the code above...that was just something I tested for 2 arrays. But I need a way to compare 3, 5, maybe 10 arrays. Yes, the arrays will be pre-sorted before this method is called...but I just don't know how many there will be. And if I loop through the indexes of a multidimensional array, that brings my runtime to at least O(n^2). :(

Comment: So, to understand your problem as a whole: you have a list of sorted lists and you the intersection of common elements among all these lists in O(N) time including repeated elements, right? Well, what's N in this case: longest size of these sorted lists, number of lists, another variable not mentioned yet in this problem?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That's essentially the problem. The other primary issue is that I have to allow duplicates. For instance, if 2 appears twice in each list, then the list that I return has to have 2 appear twice in it. Otherwise I would just use a HashSet. Oh, also I need to be prepared for basically any type of Comparable list...it might be integers, strings, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is for `List` instead of array, because handling a dynamic number of lists is slightly more complicated, but it provides support for all `List`, `Collection`, and `Iterable` types.

It works for any kind of list of `Comparable` values, e.g. `Integer`, `Long`, `Double`, `String`, `Date`, ...

Code can be modified to handle `Integer[]` or `int[]`, or any other numeric primitive type, as needed, but you'd have to clone the code for each array type.

No validation is done. Lists must be presorted and nulls are not allowed.

```
@SafeVarargs
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <E extends Comparable<E>> List<E> getCommonValues(Iterable<? extends E> ... lists) {
    // For each list: Get iterator and first value
    Iterator<? extends E>[] iter  = new Iterator[lists.length];
    E[] value = (E[])new Comparable[lists.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        iter[i] = lists[i].iterator();
        value[i] = (iter[i].hasNext() ? iter[i].next() : null);
    }

    List<E> commonValues = new ArrayList<>();
    while (true) {

        // Find value count, lowest value, and count of lowest value
        int valueCount = 0, lowestCount = 0;
        E lowestValue = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
            if (value[i] != null) {
                valueCount++;
                int cmp = (lowestValue == null ? -1 : value[i].compareTo(lowestValue));
                if (cmp < 0) {
                    lowestCount = 1;
                    lowestValue = value[i];
                } else if (cmp == 0) {
                    lowestCount++;
                }
            }

        // Exit loop if no more values
        if (valueCount == 0)
            break;

        // Save common value if all values were lowest value
        if (lowestCount == lists.length)
            commonValues.add(lowestValue);

        // For each list: Get next value if value was lowest value
        for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++)
            if (value[i] != null && value[i].compareTo(lowestValue) == 0)
                value[i] = (iter[i].hasNext() ? iter[i].next() : null);
    }

    return commonValues;
}
```

*Test*

```
List<Integer> common = getCommonValues(Arrays.asList(2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11),
                                       Arrays.asList(2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 14),
                                       Arrays.asList(2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 11, 14));
System.out.println(common);
```

*Output*

```
[2, 2, 7]
```

Comment: tyvm...this works very well. Any idea what the runtime efficiency is for this algorithm? Is it O(n)?

Comment: Correct. If you double the length of the longest list, you double the number of iterations of the `while` loop. If you double the number of lists, you double the number of iterations of the three `for` loops. Run time is linear to the size/count of the lists, aka `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works, but I've only checked it on a few cases.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arrays = {{1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 7, 7, 10, 10, 10}, 
                      {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 7, 7, 7, 10}, 
                      {1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 7, 7, 10}};
    int n = arrays.length;
    int[] indices = new int[n];
    while (checkBounds(arrays, indices)) {
        int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            max = Math.max(max, arrays[i][indices[i]]);
        boolean allEqualMax = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (arrays[i][indices[i]] < max) {
                indices[i]++;
                allEqualMax = false;
            }
        }
        if (allEqualMax) {
            System.out.print(max + " ");
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                indices[i]++;
        }
    }
}

private static boolean checkBounds(int[][] arrays, int[] indices) {
    for (int i = 0, n = arrays.length; i < n; i++)
        if (indices[i] >= arrays[i].length)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work well, regardless of the number of arrays I pass it. I would just need to modify it to work on any kind of lists...a group of String lists, integer lists, float lists, etc.

Comment: You just need to modify the algorithm by incorporating a `Comparator`. I'm not quite clear on the time complexity of the method yet.

Comment: I'm not familiar...could you help me with modifying this algorithm by incorporating a Comparator?

Comment: Actually, all the types you mention (`String`, `Integer`, `Float`) are all `Comparable` so you don't need a `Comparator` for those. Andreas's answer shows how to use `Comparable`.

Comment: I guess I"m not quite sure how I would be able to use the Math.max statement if the user passed Strings, for instance.

Comment: You replace that with `max = max.compareTo(other) < 0 ? other : max;`. `Comparable` allows you to do all of this, but it's a bit more of a mess.

Comment: @ScottUneberg This answer is nice and concise for numeric arrays, and was written before you changed the requirements to include `String`. As Paul already mentioned, my answer can handle *any* `Comparable`, but is also a bit more involved, and handles lists, not arrays.

Comment: @PaulBoddington tyvm for your help. I think I'm going to work with the Comparator algorithm by Andreas since it's clear that I need to learn more about them anyway.

Comment: @ScottUneberg Fair enough. It's definitely worth learning about `Comparator` as it's frequently very useful.

Answer (score 0):

The [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface provides the [retainAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#retainAll-java.util.Collection-) method that retains only the common elements in the source from the list supplied.

```
Integer[] a = { 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 11 };
Integer[] b = { 2, 2, 3, 5, 7, 14 };

List<Integer> retained = new ArrayList<>(List.of(a));
retained.retainAll(List.of(b));
System.out.println(retained);
```

prints: [2, 2, 7]